# Attribute Error while getting table items from dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get contents from a table from dynamoDB using lambda, however, I get thsi error, please help.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = table.get_item(
        Key={
        'id' : event.id

             }
    )




  "errorMessage": "'dict' object has no attribute 'id'",
```

Comment: Are you sure the `event` has an `id`?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing through the test event.

{
  "id": "12345"
}

I've created a table in DB with primary key as id.

Answer (score 0):

Try **event['id']** instead of **event.id**

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    response = table.get_item(
        Key={
        'id' : event['id']
       }
    )
```

Comment: I've checked this event['id'] still the same. I tried in node.js, the execution was success for this code.

`const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var tableName = "voters";

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event.id)

var params = {
    TableName : tableName,
    Items:{
        "id" : event.id
    }
};

docClient.scan(params, function(err,data){
    callback(err, data);
    });
};`